# Cloud Formation Support for Rate-Based WAF Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-waf

I want to set up a Cloud Formation in aws to attach a Rate Based Rule to my LB. I have been reading the AWS documentation for hours, and I know how to create a regular WAF Rule in Cloud Formation and attach them to my LB in Cloud Formation. The problem is I cant find how to create a Rule of type Rate-Based of  WAF in CF, there is not RateBasedRule object in Cloud Formation. Does anyone knows how to get around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After talking to aws support itself: This feature is not yet supported by aws as of today.